# Apache Virtualhost One IP multiple laravel project

Tags: laravel, apache, virtualhost

how to run multiple laravel project on one ip server with virtualhost apache

So the goals is i want my laravel projects run in one ip address ex:

192.168.200.200/  (default)
192.168.200.200/project1
192.168.200.200/project2

Comment: More details are also at https://serverfault.com/questions/956543/apache-virtual-hosts-map-different-paths-of-the-same-domain-or-ip-to-differe

Comment: @apokryfos i'm very thankful. how about if i want to make client go to 192.168.200.200/project3 but served to 192.168.200.100/project3? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need to use a proxy of some sort then [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) should be useful. Otherwise you can just use a [redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html). If you use a redirect the end user will see the new URL but if you use a proxy they will not see it.